# Deploying website on pythonanywhere gives Numpy-related error

Tags: python, django, numpy, pythonanywhere

I hosted my Django website on pythonanywhere but while deploying I got error.

I have to make project in django and ML. So i want to deploy my project on free environment like pythonanywhere. So just I started deploying my project and I got following error.

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://vishalbarad.pythonanywhere.com/home

Django Version: 3.0.7
Python Version: 3.7.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'testapp']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vishalbarad/.virtualenvs/deploy_django1.git-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vishalbarad/.virtualenvs/deploy_django1.git-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vishalbarad/.virtualenvs/deploy_django1.git-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vishalbarad/deploy_django1/testapp/views.py", line 10, in home
    model = joblib.load("LInear_regression.pkl")
  File "/home/vishalbarad/.virtualenvs/deploy_django1.git-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/home/vishalbarad/.virtualenvs/deploy_django1.git-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1088, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1376, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1426, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
  File "/home/vishalbarad/.virtualenvs/deploy_django1.git-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/vishalbarad/.virtualenvs/deploy_django1.git-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/vishalbarad/.virtualenvs/deploy_django1.git-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    from . import polynomial

Exception Type: ImportError at /home
Exception Value: cannot import name 'polynomial' from 'numpy' (/home/vishalbarad/.virtualenvs/deploy_django1.git-virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py)enter code here
```

Comment: seems like a library referencing issue, your code pointing to local path for numpy. please list down the tutorial which you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that this error is coming from a pickled file. Did you pickle the file on PythonAnywhere or a different machine? Could it have been pickled with a different version of numpy vs where it is being unpickled?